# Mysqli, fetch->fileld type to bind_param type

Tags: php, mysqli, sqldatatypes

I'm working an a php class generator. Basicly it take the specified table in mysql and generate the class accordinly. You'll get the idea:

```
....
$sql_r = mysqli_query($sql_conn, "select * from $sql_table;");
$sql_Fs = $sql_r->fetch_fields();
?>
<pre class="php">
    &lt;?php
    class <?php echo $sql_table; ?>{
        <?php foreach($sql_Fs as $sql_f) echo "var ".$sql_f->name."; "; ?>

        function sql_insert(){
            $sql_conn = sql_conn();
            $sql_stmt =$sql_conn->prepare("INSERT INTO <?php echo $sql_table; ?> (<?php foreach($sql_Fs as $K=>$sql_f){ if($K>1){ echo ", ";} if($K>0){ echo $sql_f->name; }} ?>) VALUES (<?php foreach($sql_Fs as $K=>$sql_f){ if($K>1){ echo ", "; } if($K>0) {echo "?"; }} ?>)");

            $sql_stmt->bind_param('', <?php foreach($sql_Fs as $K=>$sql_f){ if($K>1){ echo ", "; } if($K>0){ echo "\$this->".$sql_f->name; }} ?>);
                                 //^^^^ Need data type

            if(!$sql_stmt->execute()){ error_log($sql_stmt->error); $R = false; }else{ $R = true; }
            $sql_stmt->close(); $sql_conn->close(); return $R;
        }
        .....
```

Where i am stuck is to set the bind_param data type. I've found that you can get the `fetch_field->type` and it gives you a numeric value of the type (see http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-field.php).

Is there a way to directly get the letter corresponding to the data type? (s,i,d,b) or i really need to make a function to convert from numeric (fetch_field->type) to the corresponding letter?

FYI: currently it output something like:

```
function sql_insert(){
    $sql_conn = sql_conn();
    $sql_stmt =$sql_conn->prepare("INSERT INTO user (flag, name, mail, pass) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
    $sql_stmt->bind_param('', $this->flag, $this->name, $this->mail, $this->pass);
    if(!$sql_stmt->execute()){ error_log($sql_stmt->error); $R = false; }else{ $R = true; }
    $sql_stmt->close(); $sql_conn->close(); return $R;
}
```

I'm aware that is it not complete, but that is another question ;)
cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm posting my solution here in case it can help someone.

You can get the datatype of a clomun y quering the schematic of you db like so:

```
SELECT
    COLUMN_NAME,
    DATA_TYPE,
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE table_name = '$sql_table' 
AND table_schema = '$sql_database';
```

Some other intersting information you can get from this query:

```
IS_NULLABLE
CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH
COLUMN_KEY
```

official docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/columns-table.html